# Squid3 Proxy Server ssl-bump blocking Web Socket connections

Tags: 16.04, squid

I have just set up Squid Server 3.5.26 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS configured with SSL-bump. HTTP and HTTPS are working fine but any web service that requires Web Sockets fails, for example, a speed test.

I have added the following lines to my squid configuration in an attempt to force a direct connection and prevent SSL caching for web socket connections.

```
#Temporarily allow all connections for debugging
http_access allow all

acl bump-bypass dstdomain 192.168.0.245 .speedtest.net
# URL's contains ws (most web socket urls do)
acl ssl-web-sockets SSL::server_name_regex \/ws

acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump splice bump-bypass ssl-web-sockets tcp-web-sockets

#I Read that there was a bug in bump that required !explicity 
#for splice to work for web sockets
ssl_bump bump !ssl-web-sockets all

#just bump all doesn't work either
#ssl_bump bump all
```

If I disable ssl_bump and don't decrypt encrypted traffic everything works fine.

How can I configure squid to allow a direct web socket connection?

**Update**

Updated to Squid Server 4.0.21 and added to the config

```
on_unsupported_protocol tunnel all
```

The documentation says this should allow TCP tunnel connections

Sadly this did not fix the issue either, still getting Web socket error

```
Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an `acl` in your `squid.conf`?

I think you must write
`acl step1 at_step SslBump1`
instead of
`ssl_bump step1 at_step SslBump1`

Regards,
József

Comment: Ah that was I typo good spot though, I do apologize. I have updaed the question. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, in my configuration the speedtes.net working fine.
My config is here:

```
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3

ssl_bump peek step1 all
ssl_bump peek step2 all
ssl_bump bump all
```

Now, the `step3` `acl` is unneccessary, but in this configuration is not "whitelist" (not bumped url's list).

I thing, that is not big different, but I use this on Debian 8.7.

Comment: speedtest.net or beta.speedtest.net? speedtest.net uses flash which works fine for me. Where as bings seedtest and beta.speedtest.net don't as they use websockets.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, still didn't work for me. If you could try beta.speedtest.net and let me know if it works that would be amazing :)

Comment: Hi, I am on holiday, but I remembered something. I can't try it now, but be the first line the `ssl_bump splice bump-bypass ssl-web-sockets tcp-web-sockets`!
Let's before `ssl_bump peek step1`!
Do I wonder how this works?